# Stream videos from Django application

Tags: django, streaming, video-streaming

I have a Django application which generates video chunks to a folder in the server's filesystem. I need to stream those chunks as they are generated so that the users can see the output of the application as a single video in their browser.

I have not been able to find a solution in the right direction to accomplish this. Any ideas??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use a dedicated streaming server

- [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) (propritary, $ to $$$)
- [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowza.com/media-server) (propriatary, $)
- [Red5](http://red5.org) (open source)
- numerous other esoteric, defunct, or little known but viable servers

Personally and professionally, I'm a big fan of Wowza.  Solid, good value for the cost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, right now I am trying them all and I will let you know if any of them suits my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Something other than Django. Django is not optimized to serve static resources at all, let alone video. You need an actual media server for best performance.

Comment: Flash Media Server is probably the most popular right now. There's also Wowza, and many, many others. It all depends on how much money you want to spend and how technically adept you are as solutions range from hosted, easy and expensive to DIY, pull-your-hair-out difficult, and open source, and everything inbetween.

Comment: we use influxis (http://influxis.com/) streaming service for an online learning site, it supports variable bitrate streams. Amazon has an extremely affordable streaming service I haven't used it though.

Comment: @FrancisYaconiello as far as I know I wouldn't be able to feed influix.com with dynamically generated chunks and stream them as part of a single video. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

We have both Flash Media Server and Wowza options that are flexible, with great hand-holding support. IMO this sounds like a job for FMS, which we've been doing for about 10 years.

I would love to find out more :)

Wesley

-Influxis

Comment: I have already digged in FMS configuration files and found no solution for this particular need.